# Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular-universal

I'm attempting to get the Angular Universal sample project running on my local machine using Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET Core.  The link is here:  https://github.com/angular/universal

The directions appear pretty straight forward, clone it, run npm -i && dotnet restore, and hit F5.  Unfortunately, that's not working for me.  It's throwing an error when requesting a page and attempting to prerender.

Where have I gone awry?  The stack trace is below.

```
      Executed action AspCoreServer.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Asp2017) in 1725.3321ms
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL4JNIGV3L20": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\me\Documents\projects\ATS\aspnetcore-angular2-universal\aspnetcore-angular2-universal\Client\dist\main-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at findBootModule (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2BC7.tmp:111:17)
    at findRenderToStringFunc (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2BC7.tmp:116:28)
    at renderToStringImpl (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2BC7.tmp:75:51)
    at C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2BE7.tmp:113:19
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2BE7.tmp:132:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
Current directory is: C:\Users\me\Documents\projects\ATS\aspnetcore-angular2-universal\aspnetcore-angular2-universal
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at AspCoreServer.Controllers.HomeController.<Index>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\me\Documents\projects\ATS\aspnetcore-angular2-universal\aspnetcore-angular2-universal\Server\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 37
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 2358.5661ms 500
```